# Should you add a guideline as a part of the answer?

Tags: discussion, support

I came across this [C question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69971082/how-do-i-fix-invalid-operand-to-binary-error-in-the-3rd-line-it-says-it-has-the), which the first part of the answer contains:

> Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Your code is not C#, but C, so
> please tag the right language so that people can help you
> appropriately.

I think that this part should be a comment instead, because in the [comment everywhere privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) description:

> When should I comment?
>
> You should submit a comment if you want to:
>
> ...
>
> - Leave constructive criticism that guides the author in improving the post;

So, should I post a comment that contains the first part, and edit to remove that?

Comment: That is not the main problem. The main problem is that it is an answer to a typo question. The user *did* know about the comment feature, as they posted a comment begging for an accept (now deleted). Something like this should just be flagged for deletion or moderator attention.